# Moving indirect-addressed value into AL works, but moving it into an 8-bit rXb register doesn't in yasm

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, yasm

I have a byte-array of characters declared in .data

```
chars db 'spipopd'
```

and I have set rdi to point to the base index of this array

```
mov rdi, chars
```

At some point, I want to put a character from the array into an 8-bit register. The first statement below produces a valid value, but the second one causes r9b to contain `void` upon entering the gdb command `print $r9b`.

```
mov al, [rdi]   ; produces valid value in gdb
mov r9b, [rdi]  ; r9b = void, according to gdb
```

Any of the register r8b to r15b has the same effect. As I understand, both `al` and `r9b` are 8-bit, so why does one work, and the other doesn't? My hunch is that, although they are both 8-bit in size, they have some subtle differences that elude me.

The Intel documentation states:

> "REX prefixes are used to generate 64-bit operand sizes or reference
>   registers R8-R15."

Is this related to my problem?

Comment: No. The REX prefix is part of the opcode and it doesn't affect the execution of the instruction self.

Comment: How did you determine that the value in `al` is correct? I thought GDB only supported printing the full register, which means `print $al` wouldn't work either, but `print $rax` and `print $r9` would. You could use `print $r9 & 0xff` to get just the low byte, though.

Comment: Could it be that you're running the code in a 32-bit code segment and you don't have access to R8-R15? These registers apparently only are accessible from 64-bit code segments.

Answer (score 1):

"void" isn't really a value that a register can have, so that looks like gdb is just not recognizing r9b as a register name.

Note that there are two different notations for the low-byte registers, `r9b` and `r9l`, and different sources use different names.

Breaking a random program in main and trying it myself, I get this output:

```
(gdb) print $r9b
$1 = void
(gdb) print $r9l
$2 = 16
```

Apparently gdb only recognizes the `$r9l` notation.