# How do you access low-byte registers for r8-r15 from gdb in x86-64?

Tags: gdb, x86-64, cpu-registers

In gdb, I can't seem to access any of the pseudo-registers: `r8b`, `r9b`, `r10b`, `r11b`, `r12b`, `r13b`, `r14b`, nor `r15b` (however, `r15d` and `r15w` seem to work, and same for `sil`).

See an example:

```
section .text
global main

main:
  xor esi, esi
  mov sil, 0x1f
  xor r13d, r13d
  mov r13b, sil
  ret
```

Running with `gdb`:

```
(gdb) p $sil
$1 = -15
(gdb) p $r13 
$2 = 241
(gdb) p $r13b
$3 = void
(gdb) p /x $r13b
$4 = 0x0
```

I couldn't find anything in the [gdb manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_60.html#SEC61), and they aren't printed with the `info all-registers` command. I'm using GDB 10.

Comment: This has come up on SO a couple times before, as [Unable to set the lowest byte in a register x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64115162) (Ruslan's answer links the same GDB bug you did) and [Moving indirect-addressed value into AL works, but moving it into an 8-bit rXb register doesn't in yasm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10379428).  This one has a better title, so I closed the others as duplicates of this good canonical Q&A.

Comment: Wait a minute, in your NASM source I think you mean `mov r13b, sil`, because `mov r13, sil` is an operand-size mismatch.  (Also, normally you'd do `movzx r13d, sil` instead of xor-zero and a byte mov, but the point of the example is to show that NASM understands a register name that GDB doesn't.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks for fixing the code! Yeah, I was writing the code after the fact and might have got an instruction wrong :P.
Thanks for the pointers, I missed the other stackoverflow question... I searched for this but couldn't find much information, so ended up looking at the gdb code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference to the low byte of those registers using the `l` suffix:

`r8l`, `r9l`, `r10l`, `r11l`, `r12l`, `r13l`, `r14l`, `r15l`.

```
(gdb) p $r13l
$1 = -15
(gdb) p /x $r13l
$2 = 0xf1
```

I couldn't find these aliases documented anywhere, except in their definition in the [gdb codebase](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/amd64-tdep.c;h=66a7c02f53403a608122d677f5bd14aeb8df74ee;hb=HEAD#l302):

```c
/* Register names for byte pseudo-registers.  */

static const char * const amd64_byte_names[] =
{
  "al", "bl", "cl", "dl", "sil", "dil", "bpl", "spl",
  "r8l", "r9l", "r10l", "r11l", "r12l", "r13l", "r14l", "r15l",
  "ah", "bh", "ch", "dh"
};
```

Furthermore, there [was a bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26714) in the gdb codebase that would print 0 instead of void if a format is specified to the `print` command, as it happens in the last example. Future versions of gdb should display `void` if the value that you are printing is not defined.

Comment: The `l`-suffix names are actually not unique to GDB: Intel's manuals use `r8l` for the low byte of `r8`, unlike AMD's choice of `r8b`: [Why does Apple use R8l for the byte registers instead of R8b?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43991779) and [What are the names of the new X86\_64 processors registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1753602).  AMD were the original architects of AMD64, and their names are more widespread in most uses.  (But I wouldn't be surprised if there isn't any GDB documentation other than this about only allowing those versions of the names.)

Comment: I read that what's how they are called by Intel, but in Intel SDM volume 1, they are referred as `r8b-r15b`, so I don't know where the `l`-suffix comes from.

Comment: Oh, I haven't checked recently; maybe Intel changed their manuals to follow the more widely-used conventions, or maybe a different part of Intel's manuals use r8l-r15l.  The current vol.2 manual (April 2021) with instruction-encoding details also only uses r8b-r15b.

Comment: To put the mayhem to an end I chose to accept both variants `R8L` and `R8B` in my assembler :-)